# Material UI Versions for React v18.2

Tags: react-native

I am creating an Azure Static Web App to show my Azure Cognitive Search application as shown in this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-csharp-deploy-static-web-app

The issue here is that the Static Web App would not build because the following packages below are not compatible with React v18.2. Does anyone know the right versions for the 3 packages below?

```
"@material-ui/material": "^x.x.x",
"@material-ui/material-icons": "^x.x.x",
"@material-ui/lab": "^x.x.x",
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI had a breaking update years ago from version 4 to 5 and now the packages are from @mui/***. Here is the link to the doc: [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/).